# Mysql Collect data with where In condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am developing job portal web application..

Employees are registering with their qualifications.

After employees are registered successfully,

job adding with qualification on two conditions.

ie, AND , OR case.

Suppose a job having qualification with two AND Conditions like.

```
Engineering | Btech | Mechanical Engineering | regular | 80 % 
Diploma | CAD | Computer Applications | Distance | 70%
```

---

```
Engineering | Btech | Mechanical Engineering | regular | 80 % 
Diploma |  |   |  | 70%
```

After entering job qualifications I am collecting that as an array like.

```
   $a = ["27","26"]; // dummy data
   $b = ["62"]; // dummy data
   $c = ["59"]; // dummy data
```

I want to collect **EMPLOYEE ID** data from my employee qualifications table that matching the above condition.

[image]

I tried the Where In query like below.

```
SELECT * FROM `otc_employee_qualifications` 
WHERE `emp_qualifctn_type` IN ('26','27')
AND `qualification_value` IN ('59','32')
AND `emp_qualifctn_branch` IN ('156')
AND `emp_qualifctn_stream` IN ('2')
AND `qualification_mark` >= 27
GROUP BY `employee_id`
```

Comment: no too many `where`s, concatenate with `AND`

Comment: You may want to look at `AND`. `SELECT * FROM otc_employee_qualifications 
WHERE emp_qualifctn_type IN ('26','27') AND
qualification_value IN ('59','32') AND....`

Comment: Copy paste issue, please chexk updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AND` instead of `where` to join two conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM `otc_employee_qualifications` 
WHERE `emp_qualifctn_type` IN ('26','27')
AND `qualification_value` IN ('59','32')
AND `emp_qualifctn_branch` IN ('156')
AND `emp_qualifctn_stream` IN ('2')
AND `qualification_mark` >= 27
GROUP BY `employee_id`
```

Comment: hi, its not a currect query, i want to collect the data with this.. updated my question.. please check my question 1s more

Answer (score 0):

Use AND after where

```
SELECT * FROM `otc_employee_qualifications` 
WHERE `emp_qualifctn_type` IN ('26','27')
AND `qualification_value` IN ('59','32')
AND `emp_qualifctn_branch` IN ('156')
AND `emp_qualifctn_stream` IN ('2')
AND `qualification_mark` >= 27
GROUP BY `employee_id`
```

Comment: hi, its not a currect query, i want to collect the data with this.. updated my question.. please check my question 1s more

Answer (score 0):

Use AND and Change the condition

```
SELECT * FROM `otc_employee_qualifications` 
WHERE `emp_qualifctn_type` IN ('26','27')
AND `qualification_value` IN ('59','32')
AND `emp_qualifctn_branch` IN ('156')
AND `emp_qualifctn_stream` IN ('2')
AND `qualification_mark` >= 27
GROUP BY `employee_id`
```

Comment: hi, its not a currect query, i want to collect the data with this.. updated my question.. please check my question 1s more

Answer (score 0):

Try `AND` instead of `WHERE` apart `WHERE` at first time.
    `SELECT * FROM otc_employee_qualifications 
    WHERE emp_qualifctn_type IN ('26','27')
    AND qualification_value IN ('59','32')
    AND emp_qualifctn_branch IN ('156')
    AND emp_qualifctn_stream IN ('2')
    AND qualification_mark >= 27
    GROUP BY employee_id`

Comment: hi, its not a currect query, i want to collect the data with this.. updated my question.. please check my question 1s more